# Unfold/open complete DOM tree in Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, dom, web-inspector

I have a website where I don't know where a certain width comes from. It's probably a small div hidden deep in the DOM tree, so I am wondering if it's possible to unfold the complete DOM tree when in the Developer Tools.

Comment: right-click on a tree page and choose `Expand recursively` in the context menu

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source code with the right click and once you find the thing that you wanted to, open the developer tools and work with it

Comment: I know how it works, but in my case I had something about 700 pixels wide, without it looking like that, so it was quite impossible to find the thing I needed on the page itself. If I had the possibility to open all divs in the Developer Tools, I could just navigate through them until I found the one that had that width. Now it was just luck.